# How can I save integers displayed in the console?

Tags: python, pi

I created a Python program that calculates the digits of pi and displays them in the console as the calculation is running. Eventually, it starts deleting numbers that were first displayed. How could I save the numbers as they're being displayed? Here is the code:

```
def calcPi(limit):
  q, r, t, k, n, l = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
  decimal = limit
  counter = 0

  while counter != decimal + 1:
    if 4 * q + r - t < n * t:
      yield n

      if counter == 0:
        yield '.'

      if decimal == counter:
        print('')
        break
      counter += 1
      nr = 10 * (r - n * t)
      n = ((10 * (3 * q + r)) // t) - 10 * n
      q *= 10
      r = nr

    else:
      nr = (2 * q + r) * l
      nn = (q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) // (t * l)
      q *= k
      t *= l
      l += 2
      k += 1
      n = nn
      r = nr

  def main():
    pi_digits = calcPi(int(input(
      "Enter the number of decimals to calculate to: ")))
    i = 0

  for d in pi_digits:
    print(d, end='')
    i += 1
    if i == 55:
      print("")
      i = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Add them to a collection of some sort at the same point where you print them?

Comment: There are many ways, like reading and writing to a file, sending to a server where it is kept, making a discord bot to send it out in a message, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to a txt file instead of printing. For example:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
```

instead of printing,

```
print(d, end='')
```

do

```
f.write(str(d))
```

and instead of printing,

```
print('')
```

do

```
f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

On most UNIX operating systems you can use the tee command:

```
python calculate_pi.py | tee output.txt
```

This will let you see the output in your terminal and write it to the file at the same time.